# Split .txt file into 3 files based on text in line using shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed

I have a requirement where I'm getting a .txt file in output from some tool and I want to split that into three.

Example text from file:

```
First line
Second line
23456
45677
45678

Third line
90909
90678

Last line
Z567Z
6787T
```

Expected outputs:

-> file1.txt

```
23456
45677
45678
```

-> file2.txt

```
90909
90678
```

-> file3.txt

```
Z567Z
5677T
```

Basically, files will have 5 digit numeric/alphanumeric values which we want to use, and text in between works as identifier to split file into multiple files.

I'm looking to use `awk` or `sed` command to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this isn't all you need:

```
$ awk '
    /^[[:alnum:]]{5}$/ {
        if ( !inBlock++ ) {
            close(out)
            out = "file" (++cnt) ".txt"
        }
        print > out
        next
    }
    { inBlock = 0 }
' file
```

```
$ head file?.txt
==> file1.txt <==
23456
45677
45678

==> file2.txt <==
90909
90678

==> file3.txt <==
Z567Z
6787T
```

then edit your question to provide clearer requirements and more truly representative sample input/output.

Comment: how can I remove 5 digit restriction? - if I have to go for more digits but not exact. i.e., <50

Comment: Change `{5}` to whatever interval you like, e.g. it sounds like you might want `{5,49}` or `{1,49}`. See "interval expression" in [the POSIX EREs spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_06).

Comment: Great! this is all I wanted. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Here is ugly one liner:

```
grep -v '[:alpha:]' test.txt | sed "s/^$/==/g" | split -p "=="
```

Note: This will generate 3 or more files (xa*) as per "==" pattern.

You can further use for loop to remove "==" (sed 's/=//g' xa* | grep -v "^$") if there is any.

Comment: ITYM `[[:alpha:]]`, not just `[:alpha:]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use from the GNU tool chest grep+csplit

```bsh
grep -v '\W' < your_file |
csplit --suppress-matched \
  -szn1 -f file -b '%d.txt' \
  - '/^$/' '{*}'
```

---

awk in paragraph mode where  record are separated by at least one blank line.

```bsh
awk -v RS= '
match($0,/\n[[:alnum:]]+(\n|$)/) {
  out = "file" NR ".txt"
  print substr($0,1+RSTART) > out
  close(out)
}
' your_file
```

---

Using GNU sed we first generate the sed code from the input data to operate upon to generate the desired output files.

```bsh
sed -En '
  1{x;s/.*/123/;x;}
  /^\w+$/{=;$z;}
  /^$/{
    G
    s/^(.)(.)(.*)/wfile\2.txt\1\3/
    P;s/.*\n//;h
  }
' your_file | sed -Ee '
  :a;N;/\n[0-9]+$/ba
  s/\n(.*\n)?([0-9])/,\2/
  s/\n//
' - | sed -nf - your_file
```

---

Output files: in case of csplit, the file numbering begins from zero.

```
==> file1.txt <==
23456
45677
45678

==> file2.txt <==
90909
90678

==> file3.txt <==
Z567Z
6787T
```